# Organizing and de-duping a Parquet database

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I have inherited a directory of partitioned parquet files.  Each row in the table has something like

```
ID, Timestamp, partition_col_a, partition_col_b, Data
```

Some of the data is duplicated between files, so that the 2:00 PM record for ID 124 may appear in 2 files.  I need to remove the duplicates, and I don't really care whether which entry is kept.

What's the most efficient way to get rid of these duplicates? Efficiency is key because the database is enormous (multiple terabytes of parquet files).

I'm currently doing it in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd

for partition_value_1, partition_value_2 in values_iterator:
  pd.read_parquet(data_dir,
    filters = [[
      ('partition_col_a', '=', partition_value_1),
      ('partition_col_b', '=', partition_value_2)
    ]])\
  .drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Timestamp']).to_parquet(new_data_dir, partition_cols = ['partition_col_a', 'partition_col_b'])
```

When I profile the code, a significant amount of time is spent on the `drop_duplicates` call, which is expected, but most of the time is spent in reading from `data_dir` (the majority here is taken by `dataset.py:405(_filesystem_dataset)`) and writing out the table to `new_data_dir`.  This makes me think I'm using the wrong tools for this task